# Laravel Homestead and vagrant don't create the folder inside vagrant box

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, vagrant, homestead, laravel-6

I use Laravel Homestead for one year it all was good before I had decided change php version.

Firstly I update vagrant. Secondly I executed all commands from updating guide

```
vagrant destroy

git fetch

git pull origin release

vagrant box update

vagrant up
```

After vagrant up I saw that my databases were not created and my folder was not mounted (http://joxi.ru/Vm66DpgF410M5m).

I tried to connet via vagrant ssh, but there is not folder "code"

My Homestead.yaml

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: /home/ubuntu/PhpstormProjects/fntr
      to: /home/vagrant/code/fntr
      schedule: true

sites:
    - map: fntr.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/fntr/public
      php: "7.4"

databases:
    - homestead
    - testing
    - imports
    - prod_copy
```

I tried use `vagrant destroy && vagrant up`. I also tried `vagrant reload --provision`.

I have found the same issues in google and github, but this advices (http://joxi.ru/52a53oGUEBZMZ2 and other) did not help me.

I have the latest versions of vagrant and homestead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution. But I am not sure that it is solution exactly.

I just reinstalled laravel homestead. Yes, I deleted homestead folder and went via instalation tutorial again.

Then I pasted my old Homestead.yaml and init vagrant box again.

**Note if you want to try this method do not forget copy all of your after.sh, homestead.yaml and other files which can be lost**

Answer (score 0):

I think that `schedule: true` not belongs to folders but to sites, try to remove it and run `vagrant reload --provision`.